# Add Numbers to Notebook Cells

Tags: version-10

Let's save I have a notebook full of text cells.

How might I add numbering to the text cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `ItemNumbered` text cell in the **Format** > **Style** pulldown menu.